# Get from a string of 12 characters the first occurence of a character other than 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, methods

I am new to Javascript so I would appreciate some advice on my question below:

I have a string of 12 characters (fixed length) i.e. 000000000100. This value is coming dynamic to my client so it can be 000005000000, 000000000050, 000000001000 etc.

I need to get the characters of this string that are coming after the first occurrence of non 0 character.

Example:

- 000000000100 --> 100
- 000005000000 --> 5000000
- 000000000050 --> 50
- 000000001000 --> 1000 ...etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: parseInt('000000000100');

Comment: @PhilippSander, should work with a base of ten, otherwise it uses eight with leading zeros ...

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't get what you mean, could you please elaborate? e.g. an input where this doesn't work? assuming the string contains of digits

Comment: @PhilippSander, please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for pointing out! `parseInt('000000000100', 10);` should be used then

Answer (score 1):

```
parseInt(input, 10);
```

This will parse the String to an integer. It will return specifc things in case you are providing an invalid input.

please take a look at the [mozilla-documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description) for more information

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot Philip for the help

Comment: @M.Tritsiniotis please consider upvoting and accepting, so others users will find this as well.

Comment: I tried Philipp but i don't have enough reputation points. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
var NUM1 = '000000000100';
var NUM2 = '000500000000';

function noLeadingZero (x) {
  return String(x).replace(/^0+/, '');
}

console.log(noLeadingZero(NUM1));
console.log(noLeadingZero(NUM2));
```

If you need to have a `Number` as in the end, you have to convert the result.